# convert wet brine recipe to dry brine

Tags: brining

I've got this amazing wet-brine recipe a few years ago for a bone-in pork chop. (It came from Bucks in DC)

I want to convert it to a DRY-brine recipe for home use. I can take all the aromatics and make it into a spice rub. However, it calls for 2C of orange juice added to a gallon of 6% saline, brined for 2 days. Under the principle of 6lbs of meat/gallon of brine (wikihow) that is 1.6% salt by weight.

I'm going to just marinate the chops in OJ today, followed by a sprinkle of 1.6% salt an hour before cooking, and the dry rub just before it goes on the grill.

But I'm open to any other ideas for duplicating the flavor/texture that OJ adds to the wet brine. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We can quibble, but brining, by definition, is wet.  When there is no liquid, you are just salting or dry rubbing (although the term is popular, and few make the distinction).
It is unlikely that any oj, or anything other than salt molecules are penetrating the meat.  So, the oj is just a surface treatment, as is most marination. If you like the texture of brined pork, why mess with the oj brine?  I would use the oj brine, then right before grilling, use your spice rub without the salt.

Comment: No need to quibble on semantics. I prefer a “dry brine” for everyday cooking. Usually 1% salt at least an hour before cooking. The issue with OJ is maybe the tenderizing effect of citrus juice on meat?!??

Comment: @michael could possibly toughen your pork depending on length of time.

Comment: So I let it sit in OK for a few hours, then patted dry and salted. Just before cooking I added the dry rub. The flavor was spot on, but it was a little touch. However, I the chop was thinner than usual and I may have over cooked it. Near the bone it was excellent!